# Android DatePicker dialog, date should come from tomorrow

Tags: java, android

```
 Calendar calender = Calendar.getInstance();
    final CustomDatePickerDialog pickerDialog = new CustomDatePickerDialog(LabCheckOutActivity.this,
    myDateListener, calender.get(Calendar.YEAR), calender.get(Calendar.MONTH),
    calender.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH)+1);
    pickerDialog.getDatePicker().setMinDate(System.currentTimeMillis()-1000);
    pickerDialog.show();
```

by Using this code, in dialog date is pointed to tomorrow but user can also select todays date.I want user can select date from tomorrow not today.

public class CustomDatePickerDialog extends DatePickerDialog {

```
int maxYear;
int maxMonth;
int maxDay;

public CustomDatePickerDialog(Context context, OnDateSetListener callBack, int year, int monthOfYear, int dayOfMonth) {
    super(context, callBack, year, monthOfYear, dayOfMonth);
}

public void setMaxDate(long maxDate) {
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB) {
        getDatePicker().setMaxDate(System.currentTimeMillis());
    } else {
        final Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
        c.setTimeInMillis(maxDate);
        maxYear = c.get(Calendar.YEAR);
        maxMonth = c.get(Calendar.MONTH);
        maxDay = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
    }
}

@Override
public void onDateChanged(DatePicker view, int year, int monthOfYear, int dayOfMonth) {
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB) {
        super.onDateChanged(view, year, monthOfYear, dayOfMonth);
    } else {
        if (year > maxYear)
            view.updateDate(maxYear, maxMonth, maxDay);

        if (monthOfYear > maxMonth && year == maxYear)
            view.updateDate(maxYear, maxMonth, maxDay);

        if (dayOfMonth > maxDay && year == maxYear && monthOfYear == maxMonth)
            view.updateDate(maxYear, maxMonth, maxDay);
    }
}

}
```

Comment: Are you sure that you should set maxDate not minDate?

Comment: i want only min date should tomorrow @LunaVulpo

Comment: 1000ms does not equal a day, it is just one second.A day is  1000 * 60 * 60 * 24 milliseconds.

Comment: @AbhishekKumar, Rishabh Mauarya solution is correct in below answer. You can check my answer for complete implementation :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use

```
pickerDialog.getDatePicker().setMinDate(System.currentTimeMillis()+24*60*60*1000);//where 24*60*60*1000 represents the total timestamp for one day
```

instead of

```
  pickerDialog.getDatePicker().setMinDate(System.currentTimeMillis()-1000);
```

Comment: My Application is crashing in this line today.. pickerDialog.getDatePicker().setMinDate(System.currentTimeMillis()+24*60*60*1000);

Comment: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: fromDate: Sun Apr 02 10:20:43 GMT+05:30 2017 does not precede toDate: Sun Apr 02 10:20:43 GMT+05:30 2017

Answer (score 3):

Please see complete implementation below:

**DialogFragment class**

```
public class DatePickerFragment extends DialogFragment implements DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener
{

    public DatePickerFragment()
    {

    }

    public void setiDateTimeListener(IDateTimeListener iDateTimeListener)
    {
        this.iDateTimeListener = iDateTimeListener;
    }

    @Override
    public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        // Use the current date as the default date in the picker
        final Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
        int year = c.get(Calendar.YEAR);
        int month = c.get(Calendar.MONTH);
        int day = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);

        DatePickerDialog datePickerDialog = new DatePickerDialog(getActivity(), this, year, month, day);

        //        Set minimum date as tommorw
        datePickerDialog.getDatePicker().setMinDate(System.currentTimeMillis() + 24*60*60*1000);

        //        If need to set max date then use this also
        //        datePickerDialog.getDatePicker().setMaxDate(System.currentTimeMillis());

        // Create a new instance of DatePickerDialog and return it
        return datePickerDialog;
    }

    @Override
    public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int monthOfYear, int dayOfMonth)
    {
        try
        {
            String selectedDt = dayOfMonth+"-"+(monthOfYear + 1)+"-"+year;

            iDateTimeListener.onDateSet(selectedDt);

        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}
```

**Interface** must be implemented in date picker calling class

```
public interface IDateTimeListener
{
    public void onDateSet(String date);
}
```

**Calling dialog fragment**

```
public void showDatePickerDialog()
{
    DatePickerFragment datePickerFragment = new DatePickerFragment();
    datePickerFragment.setiDateTimeListener(this);
 datePickerFragment.show(getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager(),"datePicker");
}
```

Comment: Yesterday , your code is working fine but today its showing error.

Comment: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: fromDate: Sun Apr 02 10:20:43 GMT+05:30 2017 does not precede toDate: Sun Apr 02 10:20:43 GMT+05:30 2017

Comment: this line application is crashing.. pickerDialog.getDatePicker().setMinDate(System.currentTimeMillis()+ 24*60*60*1000);

Comment: I have checked again its working fine. Are you using `datePickerDialog.getDatePicker().setMaxDate(System.currentTimeMillis());`? If yes then it must be greater then `setMinDate()` otherwise it will throw `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException`.

Comment: I am using this in my setMaxDate
pickerDialog.getDatePicker().setMaxDate(System.currentTimeMillis()+(1000*60*60*24*7));

Answer (score 0):

```
   if (CustomVerticalCalendarView.isPreviousDateDisabled()) { // disable previous date disable flow
                int daysOfYear = listCalender.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR);
                int currentDate = today.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR);
                int listYear = listCalender.get(Calendar.YEAR);
                int currentYear = today.get(Calendar.YEAR);
                if (daysOfYear < currentDate || listYear < currentYear) {
                    checkBox.setEnabled(false);
    checkBox.setTextColor(ContextCompat.getColor(checkBox.getContext(), R.color.dark_gray));
                }
            }
```

Hope this code helps you.